# Laravel database notification using 2 order by

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

Hi I would like to ask in my code I have 2 `orderBy` on notification , but its just not working , look like its 2 order have conflict are there any work around ?

I want to display notification like, **1st unread** notification, **2nd read** notification order by latest `created_at`

```
<?php

    namespace Illuminate\Notifications;
    
    trait HasDatabaseNotifications
    {
        /**
         * Get the entity's notifications.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
         */
        public function notifications()
        {
            return $this->morphMany(DatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')
            ->orderBy('read_at', 'asc')  //order by unread , unread display first 
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')  //latest record display first based on created_at
            ;
        }
```

By default laravel order notification based on `created_at desc`, so I added `orderBy('read_at', 'asc')`, this command will order unread notification first , but the read notification is not `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` so whenever I put first it will execute in above example unread notification will display first, 2nd order by not working,
if I put

```
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') 
->orderBy('read_at', 'asc')
```

unread notification order is not working , but `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` this works.
Are there any other turnaround for this? I want 1st order by unread second order by latest read thanks

How I retrieve inside controller

```
$notifications = $user->notifications ;
```

I try collection but it fails

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, Laravel apply a `order by` clause in the `notifications` relation, which come from the `Illuminate\Notifications\HasDatabaseNotifications`. But you can overwrite and adapt to your needs. For example:

In your User model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(DatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')
            ->orderByRaw("case when read_at IS NULL then 0 else 1 end")
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reorder()` to remove any orderBy already setted:

> The reorder method allows you to remove all the existing orders and optionally apply a new order.:

```
$user->reorder()->orderBy('read_at', 'asc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```